# Cocos Application did go into background callback not working

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cocos2d-x, marmalade

I am developing a game using Marmalade 7.10 and Cocos2d-X 2.2.6 and I am having a problem with the `applicationDidEnterBackground` and the `applicationWillEnterForeground` methods in the `AppDelegate` class.

I've done some tests in the simulator and in actual devices with both Android and iOS and these methods are never called when I press the home button.

Could you help me? Have I missed some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature is unimplemented, you can implement it yourself registering 2 callbacks with s3eDeviceRegister() in main() for S3E_DEVICE_PAUSE / S3E_DEVICE_UNPAUSE, then calling respectively:

```
CCApplication::sharedApplication()->applicationDidEnterBackground() ;
CCApplication::sharedApplication()->applicationWillEnterForeground() ;
```

from the callbacks.

Comment: Hi, I've added these lines to register the S3E callbacks: `s3eDeviceRegister(S3E_DEVICE_PAUSE, AppDelegate::devicePauseCallback, this);` and `s3eDeviceRegister(S3E_DEVICE_UNPAUSE, AppDelegate::deviceUnpauseCallback, this);`. Both of them reference two static functions on my `AppDelegate` class which in turn call the `applicationDidEnterBackground()` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` methods. After that everything worked fine!